# How to count bytes of data stored inside a DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, size

Assume we have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataTable. Is there a simple yet realiable way to determine the total size of the stored data (in bytes) inside the DataTable?

Comment: what do you mean total size.. do you want the DataTable.Rows.Count() ?

Comment: Total size of data in bytes

Comment: why do you need the total size of the data in bytes can you clarify what it is you're trying to do..perhaps you are only needing total records count..

Comment: The data will be extracted and passed on into a different architecture. No details yet, but the size needs to be known.

Comment: This is very vague - `DataTable`s hold data that is not related to the actual existence of the records in the `DataTable`, but is more-or-less `Meta-data` attached to the object, and would give you an inflated number. You would likely have to query each row and calculate it individually.

Comment: @EBrown that is the challenge

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number of cells, you can get that by multiplying columns by rows:

```
int cells = tbl.Columns.Count * tbl.Rows.Count;
```

If you want size in bytes, you could try serializing the datatable and measuring the size, but that won't be 100% accurate, since it will add some boilerplate.

Comment: I've been thinking of serializing data too, but as you mentioned, accuracy is not guaranteed